# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Vs Checking view existing or not?

Tags: mysql, performance, view, mariadb

I am using Maria DB 5.5 version and it does not allow clause ‘CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS’ while view creation. As requirement, I need to check whether view existing or not while creation.

Here I have 2 approach for this problem …

1. Do SQL using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and create the view only if view is not present
2. Use ‘CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW’ so that no error/warning should throw if view is already present if view might have to handle more than 50k records.

Out of these 2 options, which options is better & recommended approach?

Comment: Why do you need to do this so often??  Seems like you would create the view(s) once, then not need to do it again.

Comment: Every user having own private DB so  need  to  create this view for all users private DB...

Comment: Are you aware that views do not store any data — they store a query. Replacing a view is very quick, no matter how much data the view "handles". A view, at least in MySQL/MariaDB, is more like an **alias** than a table.

Answer (score 2):

If you must know whether the view existed before your operation, using the information schema is helpful.

Otherwise, CREATE OR REPLACE is much simpler. Your view definition can stand alone as a DDL statement.

The first option requires the server to process several queries, so it will take slightly longer than the second option.  But view creation (in MySQL and MariaDB) is very fast: no actual data is retrieved until you use the view in a query.

Answer (score 0):

So the `VIEW` contains an ever-growing `UNION` across many databases.  So, the only way the `VIEW` would not exist is when two new users are updating the view 'simultaneously'.

Suggested workaround:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('update_view');
DROP VIEW ...;
CREATE VIEW ...;
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('update_view');
```

This avoids the need for `OR REPLACE` (etc), except for the very first time -- when the `DROP VIEW` will complain that the `VIEW` does not exist.  That can be solved by creating a dummy `VIEW` when the machine is first configured.

(Study the parameters on `GET_LOCK`.)